# Python OpenPyxl inserting Histogram to Excel

Tags: python, matplotlib, openpyxl

I have been using OpenPyxl for creating Excel workbooks using data from other CSV files.

Currently I want to insert a histogram into the worksheet based on a numerical list that I have as variable `x` below. 
I cannot find an efficient way to generate the histogram, the option I opted for was generate the histogram in matplotlib save and then place in worksheet, however this seems combersome and I feel like I am missing some synthax to directly pass the `plt` to the `img`.

The option using `Reference` seems imperfect also as I have `10^6` length vectors and would rather not write them to this file.

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
x = np.random.rand(100)
plt.clf()
plt.hist(x, bins=10)
plt.savefig('temp1.png')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('temp1.png',size=(300,300))
img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))
ws.add_image(img)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x)
plt.savefig('temp2.png')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('temp2.png',size=(300,300))
img.anchor(ws.cell('A15'))
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save("trial.xlsx")
```

As you can see this generates two `.png` files and overall seems unclean. I do not think the preformance is taking much of a hit but undoubtedly will have better solutions and optimization is valued here.
I would treat answers of the form: "Swap from using OpenPyxl to ..." as a last resort only.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Excel has no idea what a MatPlotLib object is so you have to use a bitmap if you don't want to put all the relevant data points into the spreadsheet.

Comment: @CharlieClark I guess this does answer the question perhaps further I was hoping for a method that would pass the current plt output to a bitmap without the need to save as .png?

Comment: It would be easy enough in your own code to do just that. Maybe pillow could do it? Expecting openpyxl to do it is a bit daft: it would add a dependency on matplotlib to what is essentially a file format library.

Comment: @CharlieClark Fair enough I was hoping matplotlib itself might. 
Something along the lines of: plt.bitmap(). If you have time I would appreciate the answer you mentioned earlier as I have no experience with pillow. I will then get to test if that is a faster solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to be worried about the "overhead" of creating a image object in memory twice. I wouldn't worry about that. It's necessary for the metadata and also because there is no common image data type that can be passed around. I'd be surprised if matplotlib isn't using Pillow/PIL when creating the actual image file. But again that's just managing file formats.

Comment: @CharlieClark Again this is just an example I am outputting around 100 .png files at the moment, and each has to have a unique name(try naming both 'temp.png' above). This is clutter that I have to clean internally or externally.

Comment: That's quite clearly the responsibility of your code and easy enough to solve. But you might find some advantage by hooking in directly to the internal openpyxl API, which is now more or less stable.